# how to download pdf in nodejs + express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to fill pdf and that pdf need to download.but I am not able to download that pdf
I am using this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pdftk

from the client, I am requesting like this

**Get Request**

http://localhost:3000/api/joining-form/navasd.sharma@asda.com

```
export const sendGetRequest = (url, config = {}) => {
    return axios.get(url, config);
}
```

[image]

```
const buf = await pdftk
                .input('templates/joining-form.pdf')
                .fillForm(data)
                .flatten()
                .output()
            res.send(buf);
```

[image]

currently getting this output

```
%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj 
<<
/FormType 1
/Subtype /Form
/Resources 
<<
/Font 
<<
/Helv 2 0 R
>>
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
>>
/Type /XObject
/BBox [0 0 362.4 28.8]
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 87
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]
>>
stream
```

Comment: no if i used `window.open('url' ).then it show

Comment: if you direct type in new tab then it show.but when I fire get request then it don't show

Comment: Browsers know how to display pdfs so they don't offer a download prompt, you can change that setting a different content-type header or use an `<a href="pathtofile.pdf" download="filename.pdf">download</a>` link. `axios.get()` will not prompt the user to download a file.

Comment: @RolandStarke how to send `token`

Comment: it will always download pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client side, you can create a downloadable link base on the request response,

Try this:

```
sendGetRequest(
  "http://localhost:3000/api/joining-form/navasd.sharma@asda.com",
  {
    responseType: "blob" // important
  }
).then(response => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute("download", "file.pdf");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```